# Sorry some thing went wrong while creating new search service application in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, searchserviceapplication

I have an issue with my SSA, I have deleted the old one as it was corrupted and now when I am trying to create a new one I am receiving the attached error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open the **web.config** file for CA via `IIS > localhost > Sites > SharePoint Central Administration > right click > Explore`.

Search for `enableSessionState` and then set it to **true**.

[image]

Also make sure you have `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule` in the file:

```
<httpModules> 
    <add name = "Session" type = "System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" /> 
</httpModules>
```

References:
[Session state can only be used when enableSessionState is set to true Error.](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/110984/session-state-can-only-be-used-when-enablesessionstate-is-set-to-true-error)